# Visual Studio Code - [cordova-debug-adapter] TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic2, visual-studio-code

I'm creating an Ionic2 app, using Visual Studio Code for my text editor.  Running the app via the ionic CLI works great, but debugging is inconvenient.

I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code's Cordova Tools extension to debug, but each debug configuration I try gives the error below.  Any idea what I can do to get this debugging running?  I tried just throwing a 'protocol' element in the launch.json file but that didn't work.

```
[cordova-debug-adapter] TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
```

Comment: File an issue on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cordova

Comment: Thanks for that advice.  I filed an issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues/202

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the related GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cordova/issues/202).

**Summary**: This error happens when trying to debug into a cordova platform that has not been added yet.  For example, run below for adding the android platform before trying to debug with android in VS Code.  (the Ionic CLI has similar commands).

```
cordova platform add android
```